# Bukkit ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on Checking for an Argument

Tags: java, javascript, indexoutofboundsexception, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to create a Bukkit plugin and I keep getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception when I try to check if an argument exists.
Here is what I have tried

`if(args[4].equals(null))`

Why is this happening?

Comment: Links can go away. Any relevant information should be included as part of your question. If it is too long, you need to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

If you have less than 5 arguments, `args[4]` would give you that exception. You have to check that `args.length >= 5` before accessing `args[4]`.

Looking at your code, you only check that `args.length>=2`. You never check for a number higher than 2.